# Android studio and Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, linux-mint

Please I want to find out if Android studio on Linux (Linux Mint especially) works smoothly. Why I say this is that I once used Linux mint but Android studio was not working as fast as it was on windows, I am not sure if it is something I did. I actually want to go back to using Linux but before that, I want to hear from someone who actively develops with Android studio on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it do work smoothly.

Android Studio itself works with pretty much the same speed on windows, Linux and mac os. I’ve tested that on the same machine. Gradle build feels bit faster on Linux based os.
Actually there is not much difference between supported platforms for the developer, I would say it is all about the preferences. Faster the hardware, one that has ssd and more ram faster the application will run whether it is Android Studio or any other applications.

But based on my experience it takes fewer more minutes to build up on windows machine as compared to Linux(for Ubuntu or mint).On Ubuntu, Instant Run is faster. Building and Indexing are faster. Creating Activities, Fragments, Classes are faster. Syncing gradle too is faster.